# Prestashop 1.7.x Register Javascript 1.7 inline

Tags: javascript, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to register a Javascript file within an module by using registerJavascript(). While using it with `inline => false`, everything works fine. However I want it to be inlined, so I use `inline => true` and the debug tool throws an error:

Are inline .js files handled different? What's my error?

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/modules/xxx/js/cookieconsent.inline.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

the function itself within mymodule.php

```
public function hookActionFrontControllerSetMedia( $params ) {

...

$this->context->controller->registerJavascript(
        'cookieconsentinline',
        'modules/' . $this->name . '/js/cookieconsent.inline.js', [
            'position' => 'bottom',
            'inline' => true,
            'priority' => 100,
        ]
    );

...

}
```

It also doesn't work with `_PS_MODULE_DIR_` or `$this->dir either`.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not work for me either. But you can register javascript by header hook. This is among others in the module ps_shoppingcart.

```
...

        public function hookHeader()
    {
        if (Configuration::isCatalogMode()) {
            return;
        }

        if (Configuration::get('PS_BLOCK_CART_AJAX')) {
            $this->context->controller->registerJavascript('modules-shoppingcart', 'modules/'.$this->name.'/ps_shoppingcart.js', ['position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 150]);
        }
    }
    ....
    public function install()
    {
        return
            parent::install()
                && $this->registerHook('header')
                && $this->registerHook('displayTop')
                && Configuration::updateValue('PS_BLOCK_CART_AJAX', 1)
        ;
    }
```